# how to you access :headers inside compojure function

Tags: clojure, http-headers, compojure

org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"
ring "1.1.8"
compojure "1.1.5"
clout "1.1.0"

```
(defroutes rest-routes
    (GET "/" [] "<p> Hello </p>")
    (POST "/api/v1/:stor/sync" [stor] (start-sync stor))
    (POST ["/api/v1/:stor/:txn/data/:file" :file #".*"] [stor txn file] (txn-add stor txn file))
    (ANY "*" [] "<p>Page not found. </p>"))
```

In the second POST, I also want to pass all http-headers to "txn-add" handler. I did lot of google and look through the code, but couldn't find anything useful.

I know, I can use the following to pass headers (but then it doesn't parse url request),

```
(POST "/api/v1"
  {headers :headers} (txn-add "dummy stor" "dummy txn" headers))
```

Also, how do I pass the content (i.e. :body) of POST request to "txn-add" ?

Comment: If you have found the solution make sure to mark the answer correct.

Answer (score 11):

If the second argument to GET, POST etc is not a vector, it's a destructuring binding form for `request`. That means you can do things like:

```
(GET "/my/path"
   {:keys [headers params body] :as request} 
   (my-fn headers body request))
```

To pick out the parts of `request` you want. See [the Ring SPEC](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/SPEC) and [Clojure's docs on binding & destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29)

Comment: I'm somewhat new to clojure as a whole (just been two weeks into this). Therefore, not sure if I understood your answer. However, I need to parse "url" portion for [stor txn file] and then need to pass :headers as well in `(POST ["/api/v1/:stor/:txn/data/:file" :file #".*"] [stor txn file] (txn-add stor txn file))`. So, I need combination of vector argument and destructuring binding form, how to achieve that

Answer (score 6):

The whole request map can be specified in the bindings using `:as` keyword in bindings and then used to read headers or body :

```
(POST ["/api/v1/:stor/:txn/data/:file" :file #".*"] 
      [stor txn file :as req] 
      (my-handler stor txn file req))
```

Comment: thanks. It did the magic (however it is still a black magic to me, as I couldn't figure this out by staring through compojure code on github). Now, I'm able to pass all the parameters (url compnonents and headers) to the handler.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/blob/master/src/compojure/core.clj#L66 for how the bindings are handled

Comment: Thanks Ankur. Looking at implementation of 'vector-bindings', things are now clear to me as how it all works.